# redirect to another location after save model in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I want to change location in my app after save model into database throught sequelizejs.
This code is created for email adress verification. So I wanna change location after save model into database, but I have error message:

```
exports.getVerifyToken = function(req, res) {

  res.render('account/verify', {
    title: 'Verify your email adress',
  });

  User.find({ verifyToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { gt: new Date() } }).on('success', function(user) {

    if (!user) {
      req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Verification link is invalid or has expired.' });
      return res.redirect('/verify');
    }

    if (user) {
      user.updateAttributes({
        access: '1'
      }).on('success', function(user) {
          res.redirect('/'); // This redirect not working at all
      });
    }

  });

};
```

So I wanna redirect page onsuccess but it doesnt not work. I have error message :

`Possibly unhandled Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

How Can I make redirection only if user attribute is successfuly updated ?

Thank you

Comment: Your problem is on res.render. You have already replied to the client, you cannot reply to the same request twice. When you do res.redirect, you are replying again.

Comment: @chapinkapa You can make answer if you want...